# How can I use Vim's spellcheck with ‘smart quotes’?

Tags: spell-checking

There are the "normal" straight quotes:
' "

And you have the angled "smart quotes":
‘ ’ “ ”

Vim's spellcheck works with "straight" quotes, but not angeled quotes, so this is considered "wrong":
It’s ... Monty Python’s

Even though it's not.

Screenshot, in case your font doesn't show the difference:

[image]

How do I fix this? I would prefer to get it working for both variants (it's and it’s).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ grep "'" /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l
26226
$ grep -i python /usr/share/dict/words
Python
Python's
python
python's
pythons
```

The problem is that all these words with apostrophes are actually in your dictionary file.
So if you're okay with modifying your vim spelling dictionary, then do so:

```
$ grep "'" /usr/share/dict/words | sed "s/'/’/g" >> ~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
```

This will

- `grep` to find all words in your system dictionary that contain an apostrophe (`'`);
- `sed` to change the straight quotes to smart quotes (that's `s/'/’/g`, where the first quote is straight and the second is smart); and
- append it to your language dictionary (replace with whatever your language is).

You will need to recompile this to a `.spl` file, which you can do from Vim:

```
:mkspell! ~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
```

If you want to use the actual spell files that Vim uses as a starting place (instead of your system dictionary), you can use the `:spelldump` command.
The output will include *all* the words Vim uses for the current `spelllang`, *including* those already added from the `.add` file.
Save the result of `:spelldump` to a file and remove the first two lines (header info), then use the same commands as above.
You may also want to pipe it through `uniq` as well, to remove duplicate entries.
(No need to `sort`; the output of `:spelldump` is already sorted.)

Comment: Why do you use `'s` as a pattern? Isn't just searching for `'` correct, asl well? This will miss words that have a `'`  in a different location (such as `you'd`, `you've`, etc.)

Comment: Yep, you're right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks :-) I wasn't sure if you did that with a reason, so was hesitant to edit it myself...

Comment: If you choose to go the `:mkspell!` route, you may also want to filter out words that are intended for irrelevant regions.

Answer (score 4):

As of now, you can simply download and compile a new spell file for the VIM. The Unicode quotes were added to the current version of the English dictionary.

Steps, based on [this article](http://henry.precheur.org/vim/create_spell_file_for_vim):

1. Create directory `~/.vim/spell` and change to it. (The path is part of VIM's `runtimepath`.)
2. For English language, the dictionary can be downloaded [here](http://wordlist.aspell.net/dicts/). (Alternatively: from [LibreOffice repo](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/tree/en) - you need both `.dic` and `.aff` files.)

   N.B. For better results, I would recommend getting both en_US and en_GB. en_GB dictionary could be found in the LibreOffice repo.
3. Unzip the file:

   ```
   unzip -x hunspell-en_US-2017.01.22.zip
   ```

   The archive must at least contain these files: `en_US.aff` and `en_US.dic`.
4. Start VIM (in the `~/.vim/spell` directory) and in VIM execute the command: `:mkspell! en en_US`

   Or if you have also downloaded en_GB files: `:mkspell! en en_US en_GB`
5. Exit VIM, and check the files in the current directory. There should be file `en.utf-8.spl` created.
6. Done!

Now, after you start VIM and activate the spell-checking for English language, it should first pick the freshly created `.spl` file from `~/.vim/spell` which already contains support for the Unicode quotes. At least that how it worked for me.