# How to use a UTF8 character as part of the iskeyword setting?

Tags: unicode

I would like to be able to add the ’ character to `iskeyword` setting.  I'm currently using this:

```
" Count ’ as a part of words like I’m and you’re¬
au FileType plaintex,context,tex,latex,mail,markdown,textile,text set iskeyword+=’
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting and invalid keyword argument for this on my version of vim.  I believe I'm using the latest vim for my system:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 25 2015 19:31:37)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-622
Compiled by Homebrew
```

Should I be specifying this differently?  Is it possible to add UTF8 characters to the `iskeyword` setting?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the character with '/'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:help 'iskeyword'` points to `:help 'isfname'` which says:

> only the characters up to 255 are specified with this option

Since `’` (`U+2019`) is not part of the ASCII (0-127) or Extended ASCII (128-255) tables you can't add it or remove it from `'iskeyword'`.

Which is a good thing because it is used as an apostrophe and thus *can't* be considered part of a word.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, but in case anyone else stumbles into this the way I did, here's a link to [the basic solution](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-can-i-use-vims-spellcheck-with-smart-quotes) I ended up using to resolve my issue.