# Private spellings, adding and marking standard as bad in one operation

Tags: spell-checking

I enjoy spelling Latin and Greek loan words according to their original spelling, e.g. præcise and œconomy. Might there be a convenient way to add these to the spellfile (manually) and at the same time mark their modern counterparts as bad (i.e. the words that in each case have e for æ and œ)?

Perhaps the very best solution would be a script that looked up all words containing æ or œ, and, if the same word with e were considered correct, would accept the variant and mark the original as bad (and otherwise do nothing).

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is similar to [How can I use Vim's spellcheck with ‘smart quotes’](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/118/51) and [Can the spell checker be told to stop marking words with apostrophes as bad?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6645/51)

You can add your variants to `~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add`, and mark the undesired as wrong by adding `/!`:

```
œconomy
economy/!
```

Then compile it with `:mkspell`:

```
:!mkspell %
```

And you should be good to go.

You can do this from normal more with `zg` (mark good) and `zw` (mark wrong). You don't need to use `:mkspell` with this.

To do this automatically for *all* words is a bit more difficult. The æ in præcise or æther is an e, but the æ in encyclopædia or archæology is an ae... How do you know which one to use?

Comment: I'm thinking of making a mapping zæ that checks if the word under the cursor with e for æ is good; if it is not good, nothing happens; if it is good, it is marked as bad, and the word with æ is marked as good. Not quite sure how to do it yet though, but I imagine it should be fairly easy.

Comment: @Lawrence Not sure if mapping æ will work if I understand [the comments here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6629/51) correctly...

Comment: I already did it with a temporary solution: `nmap zæ yawPfærezwdawbzg`. Maybe it is only an issue with ctrl.