# Can't map German 'umlaut' keys in .vimrc

Tags: key-bindings, unicode, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to find a way to map German umlaut keys (Ä,ä,Ö,ö,Ü,ü).

A simple shortcut like this won't work:

```
inoremap <c-ö> <Esc>
```

Nothing happens when I hit `ctrl+ö`.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389290/5260921

Comment: It helps.. Though the answers make me sad.. :'-|

Comment: I understand, I have been there too :( I settled to use QWERTY instead of QWERTZ layout, which has many benefits for programming...

Comment: How do you write umlauts with qwerty then?

Comment: [faq1](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5) and [faq2](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4)

Comment: @le0m, inside Vim I use digraphs (in insert mode press Ctrl + K, then e.g. o:), and inside regular Linux environment for writing mails or so I use a keyboard shortcut (GNOME compose key)

Comment: Ok, I'm on QWERTY now.. I decided to go with AltGr+[a|o|u] for 'umlauts'.. Thanks for the tip! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Vim *(though I cannot attest if this is true for every build and version)* actually **only** handles [valid ASCII control codes](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm).

This is why when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, Vim actually gets a special "control code" (`0D` in this case), while there is no such code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>, so it cannot be mapped.

There is an interesting discussion on that very subject here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/Ym6D-kWIsyo

Comment: Actually, you'll find a very similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16748339/154480