# nmap ú ] doesn't work as expected

Tags: key-bindings

The default keybinding of vim were quite obviously created with the US keyboard layout in mind, which make some of the default ones rather awkward on non-US keyboards. For example on my Hungarian keyboard [ and ] are altgr+f and g respectively, while the physical place of [ and ] are occupied by special accented characters ő and ú. I realized, that although in insert mode I obviously need these to be able write quickly in Hungarian, in normal mode I can map these keys back to [ and ] and make my life easier and sort-of keep the default vim bindings in terms of physical placing.

So now I have in my .vimrc:

```
nmap ő [
nmap ú ]
```

To test this I turned to two commands `Ctrl-]` and `g]`. Both `Ctrl-]` and `Ctrl-ú` now jump to the appropriate tag. Unfortunately, `g]` does open a list of tags, but `gú` doesn't do anything.

Any idea why one of these work, while the other does not?

**EDIT**:
For fellow Hungarians, based on the perfect answer below, I now have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
set langmap=ő[,ú],á',é`,ű#
```

Comment: Would these help in your case?
- https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6821/1733
- https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6629/1733

Comment: It's exactly what I want to avoid, i.e. to have to map everything myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the [`'langmap'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27langmap%27) option can help you here. It translates keys when they're used in Normal mode and similar contexts.

Try the following setting:

```
set langmap=ő[,ú]
```

**UPDATE:** From feedback of the author of the question, this would be a `'langmap'` setting covering all special keys in a Hungarian keyboard layout:

```
set langmap=ő[,ú],á',é`,ű#
```

If this works correctly, it should also take care of commands with more than one character (`g]`, `[[`, etc.) and marks (`'[` and `']`).

The reason why the approach using `nmap` doesn't work is that it only covers full commands, mappings don't really apply in the middle of other commands. They're not really meant for translating a whole key, that's why options such as `'langmap'` exist.

I was somewhat surprised that you mentioned that `Ctrl-ú` already worked. I'm guessing this happens even without any settings. I imagine your keyboard driver already sends a `Ctrl-]` when `Ctrl-ú` is pressed, given the typical location of that key on your keyboard layout. You could easily confirm that by entering `Ctrl-V` followed by `Ctrl-ú` in Insert mode and seeing what it produces. If this hypothesis is correct, you'll see `^]` which is the sequence that represents `Ctrl-]`.

Comment: Ctrl-ú actually works in select mode as well. Strange. I will try langmap, and report back :)

Comment: Ok, this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: I do have to say I'm always amazed how good vim is ...