# Can the spell checker be told to stop marking words with apostrophes as bad?

Tags: spell-checking

With the ascii apostrophe ', the spell checker defaults to treating words with a genetive s as bad; can that be remedied?

Comment: I don't see this problem with `'spelllang'` set to `en`, unless it is clearly wrong, e.g.: `dog's` is displayed without any mark, while `the's` is marked as an error. Can you please provide a example and the value of  `'spelllang'` you are using?

Comment: @mMontu, Sorry, I see now that it is only a problem with some words. Examples: `potential's`, `something's`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words `potential's` and `something's` are not in the default spell file.

I checked this by enabling spell checking, and then using the [`:spelldump`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#%3aspelldump) command. This will create a new buffer with all valid words.

If you do `:g/'s$/` you will see that words ending with `'s` are separate entries.

So your solution is to add these words to the spell file. This can be done easily with either [`zg`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#zg) from normal mode, or the [`:spellgood`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#%3aspellgood) command.

Comment: I was hoping for something less cumbersome.  Would it not be possible to make the spell checker treat the apostrophe as a word boundary?  Even if there should be any word that could not be put into the genetive, I don't see much danger of doing it by mistype.

Comment: @Lawrence Not easily as far as I can see. See the "WORDS" section in [`:help spell`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#spell). You can *probably* hack the binary .spl file, but adding a few words to a spellfile is probably easier...